# Virtual host points to global document root

Tags: apache, centos, virtual-hosts

I have a CentOS 7 server with apache. I have multiple virtual hosts running on the server. But one refuses to use the DocumentRoot that are specified for the virtual host in the http.conf file. It will only use the global DocumentRoot that are configured higher up in the httpd.conf file.

Have anyone else come across the same issue. I have been trying for a while now and i am all out good ideas.

Here is an example:

This works:

```
ServerAdmin uc@site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com/public_html
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias *.site1.com
ErrorLog logs/site1.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/site1.com-access_log common
```

This doesn't work

```
ServerAdmin uc@site2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com/public_html
ServerName site2.com
ServerAlias *.site2.com
ErrorLog logs/site2.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/site2.com-access_log common
```